# Подскажите, если я создал в SceneBuilder элемент Rectangle JavaFX его можно удалить?

Tags: javafx, scene-builder

Пробовал команду `root.getChildren().remove();` но элемент не удаляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотел бы поинтересоваться, зачем нужно именно удаление элемента со сцены?

Обосную вопрос - удаление элементов со слоя не всегда является хорошей практикой, а обычно и вовсе не является, потому что обычно из объектов интерфейса программа получает данные, либо пользователь получает данные, соответственно удаление элемента приведёт к потере данных, возможным nullpointeram или access эксепшинам, либо дублированию этих самых данных в какой-либо буффер, что нерационально.

Привожу ряд альтернатив, которыми можно воспользоваться:

1. Использовать "многослойную" сцену, где будут накладываться друг на друга элементы. Пример класса контроллера, где по клику вне TextArea, она сама будет скрыта из отображения.

```
package com.sad.controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class testController {
    //Декларация TextArea, которая будет скрыта
    @FXML
    private TextArea ourTextArea;
    //Эвент при котором будет скрыта TextArea, метод .setVisible доступен не только для эвентов
    @FXML
    void disableTextInput(MouseEvent event) {
        ourTextArea.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

2. Запретить пользователю доступ к элементу, при этом элемент не будет удалён со сцены, но будет полностью недоступен. (можно использовать предыдущий класс)

```
    ourTextArea.disableProperty().setValue(true);
```

3. Запретить редактирование элемента, либо его содержания, при этом элемент не будет удалён со сцены, но будет недоступен для редактирования, но данные, которые были введены\выведены останутся доступными, как пользователю, так и из кода. (можно использовать класс из пункта 1)

```
    ourTextArea.editableProperty().setValue(true);
```

4. Сменить старую сцену на новую, где элемента, который необходимо скрыть - просто не будет существовать.

```
    //Пример метода для смены сцены
    private void initNewScene(){
        //Получаем сцену, на которой сейчас находятся элементы
        Stage stage = (Stage) ourTextArea.getScene().getWindow();
        //Обёртываем в try catch, чтобы поймать возможную ошибку при получении сцены из fxml файла
        try {
            //Формируем базовую Pane, на которой будут находиться элементы
            AnchorPane botLayout = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxmls/botScene.fxml"));
            //На основе базовой Pane формируем сцену
            Scene botScene = new Scene(botLayout);
            //Отображаем новую сцену в этом же окне, логично, что в новой сцене по замыслу не будет какого-то элемента, который уже не нужен
            stage.setScene(botScene);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Обработка ошибки, если требуется
        }
    }
```

P.S. если есть проблема понимания, что такое класс-контроллер, и почему класс из кода "не работает", потому что чего-то не хватает, советую прочитать [как пользоваться fxml](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm)